# How to illustrate both of distributions are the same

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n};X^{'}_1,X^{'}_2,\ldots,X^{'}_{n}$ are all independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$ and having the common distribution $F$. $\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,t]}(x)$ be the indicator for
the interval$-\infty<x \le t$.

Let $F_{n}$ denote *the emprical distribution function* of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n},$ given by
$$F_{n}(t)=F_{n}(t,\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,t]}(X_{k}(\omega))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{ [ X_{k}\le t]}, \quad \forall t\in \mathbf{R}.$$
Similarly,$$F^{'}_{n}(t)=F^{'}_{n}(t,\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{(-\infty,t]}(X^{'}_{k}(\omega))=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{ [ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}, \quad \forall t\in \mathbf{R}.$$

Thus we have $$F_{n}(t)-F^{'}_{n}(t)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\mathbb{I}_{ [ X_{k}\le t]}-\mathbb{I}_{ [ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}\right), \quad \forall t\in \mathbf{R}.$$

For any fixed $t\in \mathbf{R},$

$$\mathbb{I}_{ [ X_{k}\le t]}-\mathbb{I}_{ [ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}=\begin{cases}
 -1& \text{with probability}\quad F(t)(1-F(t)) ,\\
  0& \text{with probability}\quad 1-2F(t)(1-F(t)), \\
  1& \text{with probability}\quad F(t)(1-F(t)).
\end{cases}$$
also $\mathbb{I}_{ [ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}-\mathbb{I}_{ [ X_{k}\le t]}$ as well.

---

I know that for any fixed $t\in\mathbf{R},$ the distribution of $$D_{n}(t,\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\left |\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\mathbb{I}_{[ X_{k}\le t]}-\mathbb{I}_{ [ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}\right)\right |$$ is the same as the distribution of
$$D^{'}_{n}(t,\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\left |\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left (\mathbb{I}_{[ X^{'}_{k}\le t]}-\mathbb{I}_{ [ X_{k}\le t]}\right)\right|.$$

But I don't understand that the distribution of $\displaystyle\sup_{t\in\mathbf {R}}D_{n}(t,\omega)$ is the same as the distribution of $\displaystyle\sup_{t\in\mathbf {R}}D^{'}_{n}(t,\omega).$  How to illustrate this rigorously?

Comment: If $Y_i$ are iid rv's for $i=1,\dots,m$ and $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$ is measurable then for every permutation $\sigma$ on $[m]$ rv $f(Y_{\sigma(1)},\dots,Y_{\sigma(m)})$ has the same distribution as $f(Y_1,\dots,Y_m)$. So switching the $X_i$ with the $X'_i$ in $D_n(t)$ does not affect its distribution.

Comment: @drhab For any fixed $t\in\mathbb {R}$, as you said,switching the $X_{i}$ with $X^{'}_{i}$ in $D_{n}(t,\omega)$  does not affect its distribution.But when $t$ is not fixed,varying on $\mathbf{R}$,I don't know why those distributions are identical as well.

Comment: That is indeed a step further but rests on the same principle. This time not for functions $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$ but for stochastic  processes $F(t,Y_1,\dots,Y_m)$. The order of the $Y_i$ simply does not matter if it comes to probabilities. You can describe your $D_n(t)$ as a process $F_n(t,X_1,\dots,X_n,  X'_1,\dots,X'_n)$.Here can you change the order as much as you like. It does not affect the probabilities. The distribution of e.g. its supremum will not be affected.